# inline-template alternative solution in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hello I'm currently learning Laravel through a course that's a bit old. He was using inline-template in the component which made him use Vue features inside the Laravel blade. I don't know vue that much so but through searching I found out that inline-template is now deprecated. so I want to know if there is another way to do the same?

so this is the code that was implemented in the course. Initially the Vue component is added to view or hide the textarea in the replies to enable editing of the reply on thread.

```
   <Reply inline-template>
    <div class="card">
        <div id="reply-{{$reply->id}}" class="card-body">
            <div class="level">
                <h6 class="flex">
                <a href="/profile/{{$reply->owner->name}}"> {{ $reply->owner->name }} </a>said
            {{ $reply->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                </h6>
                <div>
                    <form action="/replies/{{$reply->id}}/favorites" method="POST">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" {{$reply->isFavorited() ? 'disabled': ''}}>{{$reply->getFavCount()}} {{Str::plural('    Favorite',$reply->getFavCount())}}</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div v-if="editing">
                <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
            {{ $reply->body }}
            </div>
    </div>
        @can ('update', $reply)
            <div class="panel-footer level mr-1">
            <button class="btn btn-xs" type="submit" @click="editing = true">Edit</button>
            <form method="POST" action="/replies/{{$reply->id}}">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">delete</button>
            </form>
        </div>
            @endcan
    </div>
   </Reply>
```

Apparently it's not working because the "inline-template" is deprecated, which causes the whole replies to be hidden by the Vue component.

So is there any other way to deal with this?

Comment: A component with inline template is like `<template><slot /></template>` with user-defined data for `<script>`. It seems only provide reactive data and directly show its children forever